# Eclipse preference to automatically choose a conflicted auto-import?

Tags: eclipse

When I use Eclipse's Souce->Organize Imports [ctrl-shift-o], I get sick of being repeatedly prompted to choose for names existing in multiple libraries.  It's nice that there's a preference for the order in which the options are presented, but I'm hoping for still less interactivity.

Is there a preference to allow me to choose-by-default for some specific libraries?

EG, when I'm in a JavaFX project, ActionEvent *always* refers to javafx.event.ActionEvent, not java.awt.event.ActionEvent.  And I ever *did* need the AWT version, I'd be happy to just hand-type it, or disable the feature for that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'Java > Appearance > Type Filters' in the Preferences to specify types and packages which are **not** offered by organize imports, content assist, quick fix and 'Open Type'.

Comment: Good answer, but could go a little too far.  EG, EventHandler is another common one in JavaFX, and it also appears in corba, glass (6x!), beans, and jrockit.  I'm not sure I like the idea of filtering out java.beans.*, and entering individual types could take... a while.    I'll play with it though, thanks!